# What are unlabeled Ubuntu updates on Phone?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, phone

I understand the OTA updates, but I don't understand, and cannot find documentation for, Ubuntu updates I see on my phone. I have a Nexus 4 with Phone (is it no longer called Touch? I'm confused about that, too. Is it called Mobile?) installed (15.04, OTA-14). A couple times in the past month I've seen something in the list of Updates that simply says "Ubuntu Version 34 Updated at 12 January". What is this and what's in it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The older system updates in the list are basically irrelevant if you didn't install it. Updates aren't performed automatically. Recently, the updates panel was updated to work a little differently than it previously did, and shows "past" updates. For system updates, this is I think the last available version, and the "updated at" is when it appeared on the server.

Only when you tap on the button to actually perform an update at the top of that window, is when a system update gets installed.